# Extra \endgroup with trivial document using TeX Live 2021

Tags: pdftex

When using `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021 Gentoo Linux)` and running `pdflatex` on this file:

```
\documentclass[article]{seminar}

\begin{document}

foo

\end{document}
```

It fails with:

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \the \before@document \begingroup \UseOneTimeHook {beg...
l.11 \begin{document}
```

Using `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)` works fine.

Is this a known problem ? If yes, is there a workaround ?

Comment: it works in an up to date upstream texlive, check the seminar version, texlive has `Documentclass: \`seminar' v1.63a <2021/07/01> (tvz,hv)`  updated this year.

Comment: seems to be reported elsewhere on Stackoverflow too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250736/pdflatex-problem-with-seminar-in-texlive-2021

Comment: This particular version has:
Document Class: seminar 2014/01/17, 1.61
Documentclass: `seminar' v1.61 <2014/01/17> (tvz,hv)

Comment: so you should update seminar to get a 2021 version or if that's tricky yopu could roll back your format put `\RequirePackage[2019/01/01]{latexrelease}` as the first line of the document and it should give you a latex compatible with teh older seminar